# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {i}{n^2}=\frac 12?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was working on something on some physics and this came up:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {i}{n^2}]$

Is it possible to do the following manipulation?

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [\dfrac {1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {i}]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [\dfrac {1}{n^2} \cdot \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}]$

$\dfrac 12$

The reason why I think this might be wrong is because more generally,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac {1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {i}=\lim_{n \to \infty} [ \dfrac {1}{n^2} \cdot \lim_{r \to \infty} \dfrac {r(r+1)}{2}]$

In the manipulation above, we assumed that $r=n$ but I don't see anything to suggest that $r$ "grows" as fast as $n$. Although $r$ and $n$ both represent natural numbers, I think they still might be able to "grow" at different "speeds." Does thus ambiguity allow us to select any relationship between $r$ and $n$ is most convenient, such as $r=n$?

Comment: As written, the limit doesn't exist.  Are you sure you want to sum over $1\leq i<\infty$ rather than $1\leq i\leq n$?

Comment: In addition to Nicholas R. Peterson's suggestion, you may try to use Riemann sums

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I don't really see what difference that would make if $n$ approaches $\infty$

Comment: For any fixed $n$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{n^2}$ doesn't exist.  How can you say that a sequence satisfies $a_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty$ if there is literally no $n$ for which $a_n$ even exists?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I see, the answer made it more clear. I think I was trying to do two operations at the same time, compute the sum and let $n$ approach $\infty.$

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Just to make sure, it is correct to say $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {i}=\lim_{r \to \infty} \dfrac {r(r+1)}{2}$, right?

Comment: Sure. That just didn't imply the statement you were considering; there's an interchange of limits in any way you try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac {i}{n^2}$$ your result is correct. Otherwise, for $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {i}{n^2}$$
 the limit does not exist

Comment: Thanks, I think I was trying to do two operations at the same time, compute the sum and let $n$ approach $\infty.$ Now I see what was wrong.